# How to create a map with key and value equals 0

Tags: java, stream

I have list of `long` named `list1`.
I need to create a `Map<Long, Long>` (using stream api), where `key` is `value` from `list1` and value for this key = `0`;
e.g

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
map = [ [1,0], [2,0], [3,0] ]
```

The order doesn't matter in this case

Comment: "using stream api" - is this a real requirement or just for learning purposes? With the Stream API you could do sth. like `list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> 0L, (v1, v2) -> 0L))` but a traditional loop might be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: im delete this sequence, because it doesn't matter

Comment: @Thomas `.distinct().collect(toMap(k -> k, k -> 0L))` might be a little easier. (But I agree, a for loop might be better again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to preserve the order, use `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Map<Long, Long> map = 
     list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x, x->0L, (x, y)->x, LinkedHashMap<Long, Long>::new));
```

otherwise it is simpler:

```
Map<Long, Long> result = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x, x->0L, (x, y)->x));
```

if no duplicated values expected, then even more simpler:

```
Map<Long, Long> result = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x, x->0L));
```

or just use a traditional loop (agree with Thomas, it is easier to understand):

```
Map<Long, Long> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Long x: list1) {
    map.put(x, 0L);
}
```

Comment: OP also says "Order doesn't matter in this case".

Comment: He added this sentence later editing the question :-)

Comment: Note that the 2-parameter version of `Collectors.toMap()` would fail on duplicate keys so either use the 3-parameter version (i.e. add the merge function) or use `distinct()` first as Andy Turner pointed out.

Comment: 2Thomas. Thanks, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to streams using a simple foreach:

```
List<Long> list = List.of(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L);
Map<Long,Long> map = new HashMap<>();

list.forEach(i -> map.computeIfAbsent(i, v -> 0L));
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a shame that the JDK does not provide an equivalent of `Function.identity()` that, instead of returning the function parameter, returns a constant value. So, if the inizialization of a map with a constant or default value is something that you find yourself doing over and over in a project, I would suggest to define an utility class with the following method (directly inspired by the `Function.identity()` [source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk9u/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/function/Function.java)):

```
public final class Functions {  
    public static <T, R> Function<T, R> value(R r) {
        return t -> r;
    }
}
```

and to use it in the following fashion:

```
Map<Long, Long> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                Functions.value(0L)
        ));
```